# location.href doing weird things

Tags: html, angularjs, button, onclick

I made a  on the button I have this bit of code `onclick="location.href='#/fullscreen';"` but when I click on the button this comes up in the address bar '#/%23/fullscreen'. I don't want the %23 I want #.

I don't know what is going on, please help me out to fix it !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are leading with a #, which is most likely causing an invalid syntax error since the browser has no idea where you are actually trying to go.  In most routing systems # occurs after root, so preface with a leading slash.

```
<button onClick="location='/#/fullscreen'">Go here</button>
```

Comment: Sorry for the weird explanation about my problem but your solution worked, thanks !